# Kendo UI Grid JSON DataSource not loading data

Tags: json, kendo-grid

For some reason I seem to be unable to get any more than the following in the Kendo UI Grid:

[image: grid-image]

HTML:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
    {
        transport:
        {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/home/getopportunities/"
            }
        },
        pageSize: 4
    })
    $("#grid").kendoGrid(
        {
            dataSource: remoteDataSource,
            columns: [
                {
                    title: "Title",
                    headerAttributes: {
                        style: "text-align:center"
                    },
                    attributes: {
                        "class": "table-cell"
                    },
                    width: 600,
                    filterable: true
                },
                {
                    title: "Activity Type",
                    headerAttributes: {
                    },
                    attributes: {
                        "class": "table-cell",
                        style: "text-align:center"
                    },
                    width: 100,
                    filterable: true
                },
                {
                    title: "Specialty",
                    filterable: true,
                    headerAttributes: {
                        style: "text-align:center"
                    },
                    attributes: {
                        "class": "table-cell",
                        style: "text-align:center"
                    }
                },
            {
                title: "Total Credits",
                format: "{0}",
                headerAttributes: {
                    style: "text-align:center"
                },
                attributes: {
                    "class": "table-cell",
                    style: "text-align:center"
                }
            }
        ],
        height: 430,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        filterable: {
            extra: false,
            operators: {
                string: {
                    contains: "Contains",
                    startswith: "Starts with",
                    eq: "Is equal to",
                    neq: "Is not equal to"
                },
                number: {
                    eq: "Is equal to",
                    neq: "Is not equal to",
                    gte: "Greater Than",
                    lte: "Less Than"
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is the JSON that is returned to it:

```
[
{"ActivityID":367,"Title":"Non Webinar Test For Calendar","ActivityType":"Other","TotalCredits":2,"Specialty":"[AB] [AE]"},
{"ActivityID":370,"Title":"Stage - Test SI Changes Part II","ActivityType":"Other","TotalCredits":2,"Specialty":"[NE]"},
{"ActivityID":374,"Title":"Webinar Test Event For Calendar","ActivityType":"Webinar","TotalCredits":2,"Specialty":"[FE] [NE] "},
{"ActivityID":401,"Title":"Module #1 Webinar: Learn Stuff","ActivityType":"Webinar","TotalCredits":2,"Specialty":"[AB] ",},
{"ActivityID":403,"Title":"Module #3 Webinar: Learn Even More Stuff","ActivityType":"Webinar","TotalCredits":2,"Specialty":"[AB] [AE]",}
]
```

I feel like I'm really close but am missing the last piece.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated as I'm on a deadline.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unclean, and I discovered it by accident, but what worked for me was returning Json(Json(dataList)) from the controller instead of Json(dataList).

Comment: Here's one that's slightly cleaner: `return Json(new { Data = dataList });`

Comment: @BillPearmain, 'Json(new { Data = dataList })' need server side thange the code to fit kendo, i don't think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

common troubles are with missing schema attribute !
add it to grid's - datasource, and check if it is set when you make your json.

(when plain array is serialized/to_json, the data array needs a property indicating the shema)

here an example to make it clear:

js: sample grid initialisation / datasource:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({ dataSource: { transport: { read: "/getdata/fromthisurl" }, schema: { data: "data" } } });
```

when you make / output your json, see if shema information is in the encoded result:

php:

```
 $somedata= get_my_data();

 header("Content-type: application/json");
 echo "{\"data\":" .json_encode($somedata). "}";
```

or:

```
     $viewdata['data'] = get_my_data();

     header("Content-type: application/json");
     echo (json_encode($viewdata));
```

so the json that is sent to the grid would look like:

```
{data:
      [
       {item}
       {item}
      ]
}
```

instead of just:

```
[
  {item}
  {item}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Code looks good. I wonder if you change data source creation as below . Change type from `POST` to `GET` and see if it works,

```
var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
    {
        transport:
        {
            read: {
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/home/getopportunities/"
            }
        },
        pageSize: 4
    })
```

Comment: No such luck, it shouldn't matter anyway whether it's a GET or a POST.  It's not sending any data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
    {
        transport:
        {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/home/getopportunities/"
            }
        },
        pageSize: 4
    });
});
```

Comment: Already tried that.  It's not a cross domain post anyway.  It's local to the server.

Comment: @John Swaringen i just update my code. Put your code in `Document.ready` i think that's the problem.

Comment: It is a slightly bad practice. It would be better if this code will run as soon as possible (also requests in datasource are async by default).

Answer (score 1):

You can see what part of code raise an exception in some debug tool (I'd recommend you Chrome's DevTools (just press F12 key in Chrome).

I'm pretty sure the problem is misssing `field` attribute in your grid's columns array, so Kendo don't know what data from datasource to display in what column of grid.

```
columns: [
                {
                    field: "Title", // attr name in json data
                    title: "Title", // Your custom title for column (it may be anything you want)
                    headerAttributes: {
                        style: "text-align:center"
                    },
                    attributes: {
                        "class": "table-cell"
                    },
                    width: 600,
                    filterable: true
                },
```

Don't forget to change request type from "POST" to "GET".

Answer (score 1):

What I found when inspecting the JSON coming back from the grid datasource json query was the field names were being JavaScripted -- what was `ActivityID` in C# became `activityID` on the wire...

Comment: Yes, this was my problem, thank ! I solved it by changing the ContractResolver to DefaultContractResolver https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm (I'm using newtonsoft, but there must be the equivalent option in System.Text.Json)